# Express this sum in matrix form

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I'm supposed to write the full expression $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{A}}$$ in matrix form without any sums but I feel like I need another dimension to be able to do it. This is what each element of A should be:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial A_{ij}} = \sum_k \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{k}}\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial A_{ij}}$$

Comment: What's $L$?${}$

Comment: L is just a function. But it shouldn't be relevant. All i want to do is rewrite the expression

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial A_{11}} &= \sum_k \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_k} \ \frac{\partial y_k}{\partial A_{11}}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{11}} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{11}}.
\end{align*}
Constructing the others similarly, we get:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial A} &= \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial A_{11}} &
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial A_{12}} \\[0.3cm]
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial A_{21}} &
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial A_{22}}
  \end{bmatrix}\\[0.3cm]
    &=  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{11}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{11}} &
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{12}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{12}} \\[0.3cm]
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{21}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{21}} &
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{22}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{22}}
  \end{bmatrix}\\[0.3cm] &=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{11}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{11}} + 0 + 0 \ & \
    \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{12}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{12}} + 0 + 0 \\[0.3cm]
    0 + 0 + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{21}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{21}} \ & \ 
   0 + 0 + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} \ \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{22}} + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} \ \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{22}}
  \end{bmatrix}\\[0.3cm]
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} & 0 & 0 \\[0.3cm]
  0 & 0 & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{12}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{12}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{21}} & \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{22}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{21}} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{22}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Can you see how to generalize this to an arbitrary $m \times n$ matrix $A$?

---

I assumed $k$ stops at $2$ since $A$ was $2 \times 2$ in this example, but I think now that may not be the case.  It's possible to still have a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ and have $k$ go to, say, $3$:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.3cm]
  0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_1} & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_2} & \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{12}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{12}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_3}{\partial A_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial y_3}{\partial A_{12}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{21}} & \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_{22}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{21}} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_{22}}\\[0.3cm]
  \dfrac{\partial y_3}{\partial A_{21}} & \dfrac{\partial y_3}{\partial A_{22}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks! That was way less intuitive than I was expecting. @tilper